# InputStream initializing via another InputStream in Java

Tags: java, io

Is it possible to initialize an inputstream via another inputstream in java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this could help you: [FilterInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html)

Answer (score 0):

You mean BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream()) or something similar?

If so, then yes, it is possible.
I would recommend check each InputStream's constructor API to see if they take an InputStream overloaded one.
Regards!